# What's the best or most standard way to maintain data between requests?

Tags: php, http, server

As we know, in PHP we aren't generally 'supposed' to maintain data between requests. When a request is received the Apache server starts the appropriate PHP script to handle it. After the single request is handled, the PHP interpreter closes.

However even in PHP sometimes we'd want to sustain state between requests. My situation is that my server side needs to distribute data between a number of other servers, round robin approach. So naturally it needs to be able to know what the last server to receice data was, so it can deliever data to the next server in line.

I can think of two ways to do that:

- Save the relevant information to a local file and always write and read from it.
- Write a simple program in a different language, that always listens for Http requests, to which the main app 'writes' the info and from which it 'reads' it later.

Both of these approaches have great disadvantages.
What is the best or most standard way to approach this?

Comment: Saving data to a local file sounds a lot like cookies to me.

Comment: @BigScar This is internal data for the server. Not sure it makes sense to save it on client machines.

Comment: Option 2 sounds a lot like a database server

Comment: Agreed with @scrowler. Short term persistence on a single web server would be done with PHP sessions, while short term or long term persistence for multiple servers is generally done with a database server - one database backend common to all the web servers.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski A DB will save the data to disk, only to read it again a moment later. Is there a way to save the data in memory?

Comment: @AvivCohn if it is very short term persistence for multiple machines and you don't want to do a write, you may consider using Memcached. http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php  Also, there are in-memory table options for most RDBMS.